# How to inspect outgoing email content during a SimpleTest?

Tags: 7, emails, testing

I see that SimpleTest has a few built in mail functions to check for send success etc, but how can I send a message, assert its content and then click a link within that content during a test?

What is the standard or most common way to test unsubscribe, or account verification links in emails with SimpleTest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simpletest automatically captures sent mails during a test and allows you to fetch them using [$this->drupalGetMails()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--simpletest--drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalWebTestCase%3a%3adrupalGetMails/7) in the test class.

I did something like this recently in tests I wrote for the Simplenews project, to test subscription confirmation [here](http://drupal.org/node/1164578#comment-5090662).

Comment: Thank you for the example as well, it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: It actually tests the mail functionality, is there any way to send actual mail in test cases? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/249454/25879